How to Require a Single-Line Conditional Body to be on its Own Line with ESlint
I have a large project with a lot of code. We are trying to standardize that code with linting rules.
We have several conditionals that are written like this:
if (thing) { doSomething(); }
else { doSomethingElse(); }

What I want is to make it like this:
if (thing) {
    doSomething();
}
else {
    doSomethingElse();
}

I have been unable to find any rule for eslint that meets this need. How to do?

After hours of searching, and almost immediately after posting this question, I found that the following works for me.
"@stylistic/js/brace-style": [
    "error",
    "stroustrup"
]

